# override / listen to setMethod in an instantiated object

Tags: java, android, fragment

I would like to listen to a boolean value in an object that's handed to me by a factory. and it is value inside this object changes over time.

My real use Case : 
I want to do something when fragment is visible to user but i want to do this in Application class (sort of library) so i don't want to interact with the user code.

Sample code :

```
this.getSupportFragmentManager()
.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new FragmentManager
.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
   @Override
   public void onFragmentCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     if(f.getUserVisibleHint()){
        //do something
     }
     /* unfortunately this code will executed once when fragment is created 
        but the value of "getUserVisibleHint" will be changed 
     */
   }
});
```

Since mUserVisibleHint is private 
I am gently asking is there is a way to override setUserVisibleHint to know that this variable value changed ??

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send function pointer to fragment from application or use observer pattern for it.
Lets create a interface that invoked when fragment becomes visible

```
public interface FragmentVisibilityListener{
     void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible, Fragment fragment);
}
```

And then create a class that fragment tells i am visible or i am hidden.

```
public class FragmentVisibilityHandler{ 
   private static FragmentVisibilityHandler instance;
   private FragmentVisibilityListener visibilityListener;
   public static FragmentVisibilityHandler getInstance(){
          if(instance == null)
             instance = new FragmentVisibilityHandler();
          return instance;
   }
   public void setVisibilityListener(FragmentVisibilityListener listener){
       visibilityListener = listener;
   }
   //you should use this methods in your fragments!
   public void stateChanges(boolean action, Fragment fragment){
         if(visibilityListener != null){
             this.visibilityListener(action,fragment);
         }
   }
}
```

In your fragment calls

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
        FragmentVisibilityHandler.getInstance().stateChanges(hidden, this);
    }
}
```

And whenever you want to listen your fragment changes you can simply register visibilityListener to it. For example in your application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements FragmentVisibilityListener{
     void inSomeMethod(){
        FragmentVisibilityHandler.getInstance().setVisibilityListener(this);
     }
     void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible, Fragment fragment){
          Log.i("MyApplication",fragment.toString()+" becomes "+ hidden ? "visible" : "invisible" );
     }
}
```

You can create another patterns to register this, or use `onViewCreated` instead of `onHiddenChanged` if you want to listen fragment creation.